# Is there a word similar to budget that concerns time and not money?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/budget), a definition of *budget* is an "itemized allotment of funds, time, etc., for a given period." Is there a word or phrase similar to *budget* that refers only to allotments of time, but not money?

**edit:**
I'm looking for an noun that could be used in a declarative sentence like, "my budget for a new phone is $300," but for time. Another example might be "I have allocated Saturday afternoon for that task." Although *allocate* is a verb that can't be used as a noun like *budget*, but it's in line with the idea I'm trying to communicate; that a certain period of time, just like an amount of money, has been allocated for a given purpose.

Comment: "I have allocated 10 hours for that task" is **time budget**.   "I have allocated Saturday afternoon for that task"  is **schedule**.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! For single-word requests, we suggest summarising your question in a sentence with a gap, e.g. "When I poke a jelly and it makes a wavy motion, it is ____.", where the answer might be "wobbling". This increases the clarity of the questions and allows readers to help you find an answer more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [schedule](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/schedule) or timetable. They are synonyms referring to the apportionment of time, analogous to the *budget* as an apportionment of money.

> **timetable** *noun*
>   1.1 A plan of times at which events are scheduled to take place, especially towards a particular end.
>   ‘the acceleration of the timetable for monetary union’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/timetable)

*To address the addition to your question: you can say that your free time **allocation** for the weekend in question is restricted to Saturday. Note, though, that “allocation” isn’t restricted to time - the word can be used with money as well.*

Comment: Thanks! This does answer what I wrote, but I was thinking of a phrase that matches the use of something like "my budget for a new phone is $300," but for time. I'd like to say something along the lines of "my budget for free time this weekend is Saturday afternoon," but in a less clunky way.  I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: @David You can say you’re *free* at a certain time.

Comment: That's a good point. Although, I'm trying to say that this time is occupied by something. Whether I've set it apart as free time or designated it for some other purpose, the time interval is reserved.

Comment: Actually, I suppose *schedule* could be used in that sense. "I have Saturday afternoon on my schedule for free time." Like *budget*, I could use *schedule* as a verb "that time-slot has been scheduled already." *Scheduled* does communicate a sense of purposeful time allocation, too.

Comment: @David I’ve added a note in my answer to address the clarification to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try any of the followings:

★ Time horizon

★ Planning horizon. Or otherwise

★ Time management.

While the former two mean a fixed point of time in the future when certain processes will be evaluated or assumed to end the latter show how things are planned on a scale of time.